# Creating bcp format file from local database table - connection error

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I need to create a format file from a local database table but I get a connection error when I try to run the command in cmd. Here is the command I am using:

```
bcp OrderDatabase.dbo.Orders format nul -c -f D:\Format\Orders.fmt -T
```

I get the following errors:

```
SQLState = 08001, NativeError = 2
Error = [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL Server [2].
SQLState = 08001, NativeError = 2
Error = [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]A network-related or instance-
specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. 
Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online.
SQLState = S1T00, NativeError = 0
Error = [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]Login timeout expired
```

I have checked Services.msc and SQL Server is indeed "Started". I have also checked Sql Server Configuration Manager and the SQL Server state is "Running" and Start Mode is "Automatic".

The connection string to the local database is:

```
Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=D:\Tools_TextileMagazine\CSharp_Template\Tools_TextileMagazine\OrderDatabase.mdf;Integrated Security=True
```

Any ideas to what could be wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the -S parameter like specified here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/ms162802.aspx

So your connection string will be:

```
bcp OrderDatabase.dbo.Orders format nul -c -f D:\Format\Orders.fmt -T -S localhost\V11.0
```

I assume from your connection string that you named istance: **V11.0**

Comment: I get the following error now: Error = [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]SQL Server Network Interfaces:
 Error Locating Server/Instance Specified [xFFFFFFFF].

I guess it could be the instance that's wrong. How do I check the given name again?

Comment: In sql server management studio, once connected to the istance, right click on the istance and watch properties. First one is the name, with server and istance name. Then correct bcp string and it must work fine.